# Avoid uitableview cell resizing inner labels on deletion

Tags: ios, uitableview

When I'm going to delete a cell and the delete button appears, cell content is resized. How can I avoid that?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: cell.textLabel & cell.detailTextLabel gets autoresized when I swipe the finger to delete. I'm trying to avoid that. It's not a custom cell. I'm not adding any subview manually, just using the default properties...

Answer (score 0):

Only subview of cell.contentView gets autoresized.
You then place your cell view NOT on `cell.contentView` instead placing them on `cell.view`.

Comment: cell.textLabel & cell.detailsLabel gets autoresized when I swipe the finger to delete. I'm trying to avoid that. It's not a custom cell. I'm not placing any content in cell.contentView.